# How to get div height value in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a `div`'s height in JavaScript or jQuery and change it's value in CSS.

How could I do this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: make some efforts ... read the doc. http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 8):

[This](http://api.jquery.com/height/) should accomplish what you need

```
var height = $(selector).height();
```

and you set it like this

```
$(selector).height(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty standard javascript.

```
var divHeight = document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.height
```

Comment: That will only work if the CSS `height` property is explicitly defined for that element.